# Datatype result SPARQL query in Jena

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, jena

I've a problem in results of my sparql query.
This is my query :

```
String queryBody = "REGISTER QUERY noreasoning AS "
                    + "PREFIX ds:<http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/nf78-nj6b/> "

                    + "SELECT   ?idSensore ?valoreMisurazione ?tipologia ?nomeComune "

                    + "FROM STREAM <http://streamreasoning.org/streams/sensors> [RANGE 10s STEP 1s] "
                    + "FROM <http://streamreasoning.org/roomConnection> "                   

                    + "WHERE { "

                    + "?s ds:idsensore ?idSensore. "
                    + "?s ds:observes ?valoreMisurazione. "
                    + "?s ds:tipologia ?tipologia. "
                    + "?s ds:nomecomune ?nomeComune. "
                    +"  FILTER ( datatype(?tipologia) = xds:langString)\n"

                    + "} ";
```

and my result is this:

```
-------3 results at SystemTime=[1464188665959]--------
"2447"^^null    6   "Temperatura"^^null "Bema"^^null    
"8016"^^null    -1.3    "Temperatura"^^null "Aprica"^^null  
"4066"^^null    7.9 "Temperatura"^^null "Arconate"^^null
```

What should I change to remove "^^null"?

Comment: In `FILTER`, shouldn't that be `rdf:langString`, or have you defined the `xds:` prefix to be the standard RDF prefix?

Comment: `LANG(?tipologia) != ""` is easier.

Comment: This is not Apache Jena as released.  Jena does not support `REGISTER QUERY ... FROM STREAM`.  If it is an extension, you are best asking the developers of that system.

Comment: What is the prefix `xds`? It's more common to have `xsd`, but from your query I can't see whether it's the same namespace. I see that you get results, so it seems so. But as Andy said, the output might be wrong because of the 3rd party API which might extend Apache Jena API.